# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment 11 | (*pt+9) = ((int *)malloc(1*sizeof(int)));

Tags: c

```
int *pt[10];
*pt = (int *) malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

until this line everything is ok:-
but as soon as i try to allocate memory to a specific address inside a array the ERROR occurs.

```
(*pt+9) = (int *)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding about your knowledge about arrays and pointers. The expression `*pt` is exactly the same as `pt[0]`. Which means that `(*pt + 9)` is the same as `pt[0] + 9`, which indeed is not a valid pointer.

Comment: And just ***guessing*** here, the first allocation should be skipped, since you seem to want to allocate space for the array itself, which isn't needed since that handled by the array definition. And the second allocation should probably use `*(pt + 9)` which is the same as `pt[9]`. Notice the placement of the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: With all this said, why are you even using pointers here? Why not a plain array of `int` (as in `int pt[10];`)?

Comment: i was just experimenting to enhance my knowledge

Comment: actually i have just started to learn c programming

Comment: Then you're probably trying to run before you can crawl. Please invest in some beginners book, and start from the very beginning. And take baby-steps, not continuing until you really understand what's happening.

Comment: ok boos i wiil do

Comment: I'm voting to close as a simple typo `(*pt + 9)` should have been `*(pt + 9)`.

Answer (score 0):

`int* pt[10]` is an array of pointers and `*pt = (int *) malloc(10*sizeof(int));` is the wrong way to allocate memory for an array of pointers.

If the intention is to allocate an array of 10 integers, the code should be:

```
int* pt = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

If the intention is to allocate room for each pointer in an array of 10 pointers, then each and every pointer needs to be initialized:

```
int* pt[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  pt[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int)); // where n is some array size
```

---

`(*pt+9)` Doesn't work reliably in case you allocated 10 `int`. `pt` in the original example is an array of pointers, and when an array is used in an expression it "decays" into a pointer to the first element. In this specific case it is equivalent to `int**`. And when you de-reference that you end up with `int*` type. Then the + 9 does pointer arithmetic on `int` types rather than `int*` types.

None of it makes sense, simply do `pt[9]` in case you intend to access the last pointer item in the array. In general always use `arr[i]` style before `*(arr + i)` because the latter is harder to read and much easier to get wrong.

Comment: It looks like OP's original code was trying to allocate memory blocks pointed to by `pt[0]` and `pt[9]`, but with different syntax (incorrectly in the second case), so I think the use of the array of `int *` was intentional.

Comment: Also, the `+ 9` in OP's code was operating on an `int *` value (from `*pt`, i.e. `pt[0]`), albeit an invalid `int *` value since it is uninitialized.

Comment: @IanAbbott Whatever... for all we know they might have tested one code and posted another. This answer is just another version of "if you write really weird code, you get really weird results". The solution: don't write really weird code. Feel free to close it all as "can't be reproduced".